# Using AWS Lambda to trigger C++ file - Hello World

Tags: c++, aws-lambda

I have been stuck on this for a while.

I want to be able to trigger lambda functions to run my .cpp files via lambda function.

For simplicity, I want to run a hello.cpp file that just runs hello world. I want to know how this is possible, what is the file architecture I need? What goes inside my handler function?

I know this is very simple to do in node.js, but how would I replicate the node.js hello world example to run the c++ file?

The AWS website does say I'm allowed to use custom runtime, so it should be possible.

Any insight will help.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda is now supporting C++ natively.

Announcement post [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/).

If you still want to use NodeJS, compile your program using an Amazon Linux image, and run this index.js, adding the compiled file to the folder `node_modules/.bin/` and the dynamic libraries required to the folder `node_modules/.bin/lib` in the uploaded `.zip` file:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var result = require('child_process').execSync("/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 --library-path "+process.cwd() +"/node_modules/.bin/lib "+process.cwd() +"/node_modules/.bin/helloworld ").toString();

    result = JSON.parse(result);

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: result
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```